# See tweets in CoTweet that have been retweeted (new-style)?

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to see my tweets that have been retweeted by others?  I can see the ones that count as mentions if they are retweeted using the old-style.  I am not seeing ones done by the new-style though.

Comment: Well, it's on the [request list](http://getsatisfaction.com/cotweet/topics/twitter_retweets_within_cotweet) at least...

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use *another* webapp, [favstar.fm](http://favstar.fm/) shows your tweets which have been RT'd by others.

[image]